# NullPointerException in onCreate() method while handling an event

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I created a new Android project (for android 2.3.3) using Eclipse and I modified the `main.xml` file in `res/layout` folder as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button android:id="@+id/button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button01_name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The `strings.xml` file in `res/values` folder is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">ButtonClickDemo3</string>
    <string name="button01_name">Press this button!</string>

</resources>
```

Finally, here is the `onCreate()` method of the one `Activity` of the project.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Button button01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01);
    button01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "The button was pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}
```

When I run this simple application, a NullPointerException is thrown on `button01.setOnClickListener(...)`. Indeed, if I move the `setContentView(R.layout.main);` instruction writing it before creating the button, that is

```
...

setContentView(R.layout.main);

Button button01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01);
button01.setOnClickListener(...);

...
```

the application works successfully. Why?

Comment: Toast toast = Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "The button was pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); why v.getContext()? Use the activity context (this  or YourActivityName.this)

Comment: @blackbelt: `v.getContext()` should return the activity context. Howewer, writing just `this` is an error because `new View.OnClickListener()` is an anonymous class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the `contentView` first otherwise how do you expect `findViewById` to find the views.  This is why your getting a null pointer.  `button01` is a View on R.layout.main therefore you must set your `contentView` first

Answer (score 1):

It is because your activity in the time of defining button doesn't know in which layout should it search for id/button01

Answer (score 0):

`setContentView(R.Layout.main)` is missing in your `onCreate()` method

Comment: The call to `setContentView(R.Layout.main)` is not missing. If I write it after creating the `Button` widget, the exception is thrown, else not. Now I understand that the _content view_ must be set first in order to find the button by id.